# How to stop turtles when all patches have been colored?

Tags: netlogo, move, patch, rnetlogo

How to stop turtles when all patches have been colored in Netlogo?

When the turtles have covered the world in patches, I would like the turtles to stop on the last one so that I can record the amount of ticks it took.

Here is my code so far:

```
turtles-own [time-since-last-found]
```

---

```
to setup
  ca
  ask n-of num-clusters patches [
      ask n-of 20 patches in-radius 5 [
          set pcolor red
      ]
  ]
  crt 1 [ set shape "person"
          set color yellow
          set size 2
          set time-since-last-found 999
          pen-down
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

---

```
to go
  ask turtles [search]
  tick
end
```

---

```
to search
   ifelse time-since-last-found < 20 [
          right (random 181) - 90
   ] [
          right (random 21) - 10
   ]
   fd 1
   ifelse pcolor = red [
          set time-since-last-found 0 set pcolor blue
   ] [
          set time-since-last-found time-since-last-found + 1
   ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the turtles to stop when all the red patches have been visited, i.e., when all the red patches have been turned to blue. Adding

```
if count patches with [pcolor = red] <= 0 [stop]
```

just before `tick` in the `go` procedure should do the trick.